# Managing Application & assembly versioning in an automated release process

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am managing a .net solution containing API Project, Web Project and shared assemblies.

All source code are under VSTS

And I use VSTS release for deploying project in différents environment.

Now I would like adding a version number in my web site and API site (I don't call API endpoint versioning, it's a different story).

For now the only way to do that is to Store the version information in my code and update it as any other part of the code. I would like finding a way to do that directly as part of the release process.

How are you managing the application versioning on automated release process?

Thanks.

regards,

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the version in the config file, such as web.config, then read the value in the code.

A simple sample:

1. Add `<appSettings><add key="version" value="#{Release.ReleaseName}#"/></appSettings>` to web.config file
2. Add [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to release
   Then, the token (`#{Release.ReleaseName}#`) will be replaced with the value of **Release.ReleaseName** variable.

There are many [build-in variables in release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch), you also can add variable to release too.